# Set one string to equal another string without <string.h>

Tags: c

How do I make 2 strings equal each other in C without using `<string.h>` ? The most obvious way I have in mind is below, however it raises an invalid initializer error.

For example:

```
    char str1[100] = "This is a string";
    char temp[100] = str1;
```

Comment: I usually use `memcpy` myself because some compilers throw warnings on `strcpy`

Answer (score 2):

You can't use an array to initialize another array. And you can't use assignment between arrays either.

The only way is to do an explicit copy from one array to the other. And for null-terminated byte strings then the usual way us through [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy):

```
char str1[100] = "This is a string";
char temp[100];

strcpy(temp, str1);
```

And to get a proper declaration of `strcpy` you should include `<string.h>`. There's no way around it (unless you want to write your own `strcpy`-like function which I highly recommend against).

You can of course also copy the whole array, including all the uninitialized contents, using [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy), but it's also declared in `<string.h>`.

Comment: Re “You can't use an array to initialize another array”: Except for string literals. A string literal is (or defines) an array that can be used to initialize another array.

Comment: Re: “And to get a proper declaration of strcpy you should include <string.h>. There's no way around it…”: Per C 2018 7.1.4 2, it is permissible to declare a library function yourself, without including its header.

Comment: @EricPostpischil IIRC when used as an initializer, the compiler doesn't have to store the actual string literal itself to use for initialization at run-time.

Comment: @EricPostpischil As for the declaration, the source argument is declared with `const`, and since C99 the "proper" declaration is with `restrict` for both arguments. How many would remember that when declaring the function themselves?

Comment: Whether the string literal has to be stored or not is irrelevant to the fact that it is an array (or, as described in C 2018 6.4.5 6, defines an array), which may be used in an initializer to initialize an array (6.7.9 14 and 15). Semantically, a string literal is an array that can be used to initialize an array.

Comment: One is not required to remember everything when programming. I often refer to documents. I was not making a judgment about the utility of 7.1.4 2, just stating it, as a matter of correctness. (But I will make a judgment about it: There exist occasions when it is useful to declare an isolated routine and not include a full header.)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this.  Don't initialize `temp`.  Just advance the pointers to the characters until you hit the null terminator in str1.  This will be less efficient than the strcpy implementation.

```
    char *p = str1;
    char *q = temp;

    while (*p)
            *q++ = *p++;

    *q = '\0';
```

Comment: Or turn it into a `do *q++ = *p; while (*p++);` and copy the *nul-terminating* character within the loop. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy one string to another without using `<string.h>` you have to run a loop starting from the first position of `str1` till you found `'\0'` and copy every element to `temp`. don't forget to add a `'\0'` at the end of `temp` or you will see some garbage value while printing it.

```
char str1[100] = "This is a string";
char temp[100];
int i;
for(i = 0; str1[i] != '\0'; i++){
    temp[i] = str1[i];
}
temp[i] = '\0';
```